# Finding the vertices of an Ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Trying to find the vertices of a ellipse.

This is what I got 
[image]

And so used WolframAlpha just to test it out, this is my third time using it.
This is the solution that I got

[image]

So as you can see in the implicit plot it shows that in the positive y-axis it is 2.26? would be the answer?

Comment: What is your definition of "vertex" in this context? The ones I can find on the net all imply that the vertices of this ellipse would be its intersection with the $x$ axis. The intersections with the $y$ axis would be "co-vertices".

Comment: I guess the vertices in this case will be the points of the ellipse in the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the ellipse is centered at the origin, the verticies occur where one of the coordinates equals 0.

Setting $x=0$:
$$49y^2=251$$
$$y = \pm {\sqrt{251} \over 7}$$

Setting $y=0$:
$$23x^2 = 251$$
$$x = \pm \sqrt{251 \over 23}$$

Your question asks for the positive x intercept($y=0$). That's $(0,{\sqrt{251} \over 7})$.

Comment: I have no choice but to agree with you, lol. Tks for the clarification.